# Javascript property declaration using curly brace

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties

I am very new to JavaScript and coding in general. I started with a udemy course to learn the basics and began putting what I know to practice by following along with [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2aW5V46khA). I am trying to build Tetris. The video is great, but in it (at time 7:10) he did something I was hoping for clarification on.

He declared a variable with two properties. The first property contains a value within `{}`. I have the code below.

```
const player = {
    pos: {x: 5, y: 5},
    matrix: matrix
}
```

Can someone explain `pos: {x: 5, y: 5}`? I am struggling to even articulate a Google search. What is this called? Is this used regularly in JS and for what?

Any info would be a huge help.

Thanks

Comment: `player` is an object. `pos` and `matrix` are properties. `pos` also happens to be an object acting as a property within `player`. You see `pos` has its own set of properties which is `x` and `y`. See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp for basics of object. That one example is called a nested object.

Comment: The curly brace syntax to define an object is called an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), Your example contains two of them, one  for `player` and one for `pos`,

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Object_literals and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer . If you understand that player is assigned an object with two properties, `pos` and `matrix`, then you should be able to understand that `pos` is assigned an object with two properties, `x` an `y`. It's exactly the same concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const player = {      // variable (a constant) named "player", whose type is object
    matrix: matrix,   // property of an object, whose key is "matrix" and value is something (another variable, function etc.) named "matrix"
    pos: {x: 5, y: 5} // property of an object, whose key is "pos" and value is another object
}
```

Object is, simply put, a variable that can contain many pairs key-value (called *properties*). Value may be an integer, string, ..., or even another object. You can access the properties via dot `.` notation. For example:

```
player.pos.x // returns 5
```

Comment: It's called property not attribute. Attributes are for markups. If you want to be extremely strict about technical terms.

Comment: @AbanaClara You're right, I've edited the answer. Although, in many other programming languages, *property* of an object is often called *attribute*.

Comment: Nit pick: An object is not a variable, it's a value.